# Using symfony's Dependency Injection component with other php classes

Tags: php, symfony1, dependency-injection, symfony-1.4

I'm a lit bit confused. I create a bootstrap file with service container:

```
require_once '/path/to/lib/sfServiceContainerAutoloader.php';
sfServiceContainerAutoloader::register();

$sc = new sfServiceContainerBuilder();

$sc->register('database', 'PDO')->
  addArgument('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_dbname')->
  addArgument('user')->
  addArgument('password')->
  addArgument(array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

I want now to create a class and use the database

```
class Foo {
   functon runSomeQuery() {
     // Here I want to use database
   }
}
```

How I could do it in a elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

Your could try:

```
class Foo {

    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $_adapter = null;

    public function __construct(PDO $adapter = null) {
        if (!$adapter) {
            // assuming you have your generated DI container set there
            $this->_adapter = Zend_Registry::get('diContainer')->getDatabase();
        } else {
            $this->_adapter = $adapter;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do it in other similar ways, like implement setAdapter(PDO $adapter). Well anyway, you get the idea. Or you could just use it like this:

```
public function __construct() {
     // assuming you have your generated DI container set there
     $this->_adapter = Zend_Registry::get('diContainer')->getDatabase();
}
```

there are number of ways doing this in nice way, depends how you really want everything to be.
Basic quite nice choices: 
1. inject through constructor + in constructor(in case not provided as contructor param)
2. inject in contructor through DI container only 
3. inject with separate method
4. depends what you doing/want to do, might just take the registered service through DI container and just use it, dont save it in class. (example: 
Zend_Registry::get('diContainer')->getDatabase()->prepare('>>SQL<<');